# O funcionamento de Docker Network

Tags: redes, docker

Sempre tive a vontade de ter um servidor para que eu pudesse aprender sobre DevOps e etc.. Eis que surge um antigo computador aqui com configurações razoáveis: i5, 8GB RAM e 500Gb HDD. Comecei a estudar sobre o Docker e me perguntei se sempre teria que fazer um *bind* das portas reais para as instâncias, mas vejo na documentação 'docker network' que devemos passar o ip da rede e depois conectar os *conteiners* a ela. Segue abaixo algumas referências:

- [Docker conteiner networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network)
- [Docker network create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/)
- [Work with network commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/)

Depois de ler estes artigos, fiquei com algumas dúvidas.

### Como o computador é interpretado pelos containers?

Quando crio essa network do docker, o servidor passa a ser um roteador para os conteiners?

### E os recursos da máquina?

O docker já necessita de no mínimo 2 GB de ram e etc para ser instalado, com a criação de uma docker network, como fica o consumo de memória?

### Como na vida real, é possível conectar duas redes?

Digamos que eu tenha o seguinte cenário:
[image: Imagem Ilustrativa]

Preciso configurar algo em minha rede para que do Meu Notebook consiga acessar o banco de dados x.27.1 e x.28.1 ou o ssh de x.28.2?

Quando vou me conectar com x.25.129 eu não preciso colocar o IP dele, apenas o nome ou seja:

```
~$ ssh sa@gipsydanger
```

*Sim, eu nomeio minhas máquinas com nomes de **Jaegers**.*

Então para conectar com essas outras instâncias localizadas em x.27.x e x.28.x eu necessitaria de utilizar seu IP?

```
~$ ssh sa@192.168.27.1
```

Se puder informar mais coisas que eu possa fazer para aprender mais eu agradeceria.

### Extra

Se por acaso eu quisesse criar um [NameServer](https://www.frhost.com.br/central/knowledgebase/50/O-que-e-Name-Server-ou-DNS.html) utilizando o [BIND do ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) para toda a rede local em 192.168.x.x teria que alterar alguma configuração em meu roteador? Isso prejudicaria minha performance de internet?

Já agradeço desde já e se por acaso essa pergunta for inapropriada para a comunidade por favor, me avise, estou aprendendo sobre o SO ainda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rede no docker não é tão complexa. É uma subrede dentro do seu servidor. Com o bind você faz a esposição de uma porta específica, isso é util para suas máquinas fora da rede interna do docker. 
No entanto, para comunicação entre containers, nenhuma exposição de porta é necessária. Containers em uma mesma rede docker, falarm entre si por seu próprio nome, mas você também pode definir alias para esses containers. Todas as portas do container estão livres na rede docker e só para expor para fora dessa rede que você precisa fazer bind.

Supondo que você queira expor uma porta de um container para a internet, esse é um exemplo legal, você deveria:

- Configurar o port forward no seu roteador apontando para o Host que possui o container.
- Criar o container com o bind para a mesma porta mapeada.

Pronto... com isso da internet você consegue acessar seu container. Caso queira acessar via SSH.

Um container pode também assumir a rede do host, usando a configuração de network host. Assim não são necessárias aberturas de portas, mas não é uma prática legal, principalmente se você está pensando em escala.

Se você estiver usando docker swarm, outro dado interessante é que qualquer nó é um proxy para o container correto. Todos os nós são proxies para qualquer nó da rede swarm, isso é muito interessante.